# Eigen Map<> performance

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen, fftw, pointer-arithmetic

I'm using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) to provide some convenient array operations on some data that also interfaces with some C libraries (particularly [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/)). Essentially I need to FFT the x, y, and z components of a (large) collection of vectors. Because of this, I'm trying to decide if it makes more sense to use

```
array<Eigen::Vector3d, n> vectors;
```

(which will make the FFTW calls a little more cumbersome as I'd need a pointer to the very first *double*) or

```
array<double, 3 * n> data;
```

(which will make the linear algebra/vector products more cumbersome as I'd have to wrap chunks of `data` with `Eigen::Map<Vector3d>`). A little bit of empirical testing shows that constructing the `Map` is about 30% slower than constructing a `Eigen::Vector3d` but I could have easily oversimplified my use-case in exploring this. Is there a good reason to prefer one design over the other? I'm inclined to use the second because `data` has less abstraction in the way of treating its contents as "a collection of `double`s that I can interpret however I want."

Edit: There's probably something to be said for implicit `Eigen::Vector3d` alignment, but I'm assuming `vectors` and `data` align the underlying doubles the same way.

Comment: Why not use a `MatrixXd` or `MatrixX3d` and pass the individual vectors to wherever they need to go?

Comment: @AviGinsburg Fair question! It's because the Fourier transform is actually a 3d FFT and the data require a very specific structure (zeros in the right places) determined by the problem. It's much easier to lay out values if I can do `table[x][y][z] = Eigen::Vector3d(fx, fy, fz)`.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify how you plain to index them, especially regarding your last comment. Basically, you could use a `Matrix<double,3,Dynamic,Opt> data`, do `data.col(id(i,j,k)) = Vector3d(...)` with id an inline function doing the 3D indexing. Then you can choose afterwards whether you store you data in AoS or SoA format using for `Opt`  either `ColMajor` or `RowMajor` respectively. (if that was your question)